# what has changed on the web in past months that broke Firefox 3.5 compatibility with many javascript heavy websites?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

it used to be that Firefox 3.5 rendered websites very well. Now, let's say I go to 2shared.com, upload a file and am never redirected to the page with the download links (IE8 still works though). So this site, 2shared.com, used to work with Firefox 3.5 but no longer does. Similarly, I have seen user experience degrade on a number of other sites. It's as if there was some widespread technology change in javascript heavy websites (or maybe specifically asp.net javascript heavy websites? one of the broken websites is known to be asp.net) that broke compatibility with it.

Anybody else notice this? Any ideas? Has this been already discussed?

Comment: Probably a new version of jQuery that breaks in older browsers. If the web is broken just blame jQuery since most of the web uses it and it's trivial to break jQuery

Comment: @Raynos hate much? 2shared has no jQuery so your lame theory fails. I wish comments had down votes.

Comment: @epascarello not hate, truth. jQuery is a horribly leaky abstraction.

Comment: Firefox 3.6.x is currently scheduled for end of life on April 24, 2012. Time to upgrade.

Comment: Many web developers are clueless about writing cross–browser sites that degrade gracefully and retain functionality. 2shared.com uses some pretty awful browser sniffs using `document.all` while pretending to support Navigator 3 in places with `document.layers`, yet apparently can't support a pretty decent browser less than 3 years old.

Comment: @epascarello—2shared uses jQuery 1.4.4. Look beyond the first page. And jQuery's "cross browser" support only starts at Firefox 3.6. Seems it's easier to drop support for browsers less than 3 years old that to actually write cross browser code.

Answer (score -2):

Firefox 3.5 is a legacy browser.

It's the equivelant of running your websites in IE5.5 and expecting them to work.

That's not how the internet works anymore these days.

The web is moving towards "Only support the latest version of major browsers". It's a shame that websites don't support legacy browsers, but that's how it works.